# How can I stop the characters rotations once they get to 0 on y?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator[] animators;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    private bool endRot = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[2].transform.position, target.position);
        if (distanceFromTarget < 15)
        {
            float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 15) / 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 2f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
            }

            if (animators[0].transform.localRotation.y != 0 && endRot == false)
            {
                animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (animators[0].transform.localRotation.y == 0)
                endRot = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Both characters start with `localRotation` of euler angles `(0f, 180f, 0f)`.
I want them to rotate to 0 on Y and then stop. Tried using a flag but I guess comparing floats is wrong. Should I use `StartCoroutine` for that ?

I tried to make animation clip using the Timeline but once I create a new animation track and drag in one of the characters for some reason it's changing the character position and it's weapon not attached to him. Not sure why it happens with the Timeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clamp the rotation so that you don't overshoot within a single frame of rotation. Here is one way to do that.

Set the goal rotation:

```
Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f,0f,0f); // or Quaternion.identity
```

Find how far the first transform's rotation is from that in degrees:

```
float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(goalRotation, animators[0].transform.localRotation);
```

Determine which is smaller: the angle given by the speed * delta time *or* the angle remaining to figure out how far you should rotate this frame. **This is the important clamping part**:

```
float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Then, rotate by that amount. And if you did rotate by `angleToGoal`, then set `endRot = true;`.

This could look like so:

```
if (distanceFromTarget < 2f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
    {
        animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
    }

    if (!endRot)
    {
        Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f,0f,0f);
        float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                goalRotation,
                animators[0].transform.localRotation);         
        float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);   

        // use axis of Vector3.down to keep angles positive for ease of use
        animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);
        animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);

        // We end if we rotated the remaining amount.
        endRot = (angleThisFrame == angleToGoal);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working but the reason in my question in my original code I used: Vector3.up, rotationSpeed and Vector3.up, -rotationSpeed with a minus is that I want that one of the characters will rotate to the right and one to the left and both to rotate the inside. Now they both rotating to the left or from the left.

Comment: @DubiDuboni I see now. I changed the 2nd to use Vector3.up to make it rotate in the other direction. Try that.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with comparing floats, you just to be aware of the precision - it is essentially impossible to stop exactly at 0. But what you can do it stop when it's very close, and then true up afterwards. For example:

```
if (animators[0].transform.localRotation.y >= 0.1f && endRot == false)
```

and then have:

```
if (animators[0].transform.localRotation.y <= 0.1f)
{
    endRot = true;
    // set y to zero, keep x and z rotation the same.
    animators[0].transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(animators[0].transform.localEulerAngles.x, 0, animators[0].transform.localEulerAngles.z);
}
```

depending on how fast you are rotating, you may need to adjust the margin so there is little difference between the point at which it stops rotating and 0.

Comment: This doesn't prevent it from overshooting and when it does overshoot, the rotation won't stop. For instance, if it overshoots by 2 degrees such that `localRotation.y == 358f`, then it will continue rotating.

Comment: correct, it won't prevent overshooting. but if it rotates down from >0 past zero, the localrotation will become negative and stop rotating. just tested this to make sure. to prevent overshoot you could Lerp from the original rotation to zero, and then true-up. but this will obviously require you to change how you approach the rotation

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to get the euler angle values exactly as they are displayed in the editor is with the internal `GetLocalEulerAngles` method. When you tested, did you read the output of `localRotation.y` in code or were you just looking at the values in the inspector? These can be very different values.

Comment: I used the same method of rotation and printed the value of localrotation.y to the console (the same value that is being checked to stop rotation)

Comment: Oh I see why. For some reason I thought it was comparing the euler angle component `y`. But actually it's comparing the `y` component of the **quaternion** representation of the rotation to 0, so I can see how it works differently.